# What kind of droid replaced Luke Skywalker's hand?

Tags: star-wars, droids

What kind of droid replaced Luke Skywalker's hand at the end of *The Empire Strikes Back*?

Does a protocol droid have the kind of expertise needed for that?

Comment: A medical droid., 2-1B I believe

Comment: I totally thought you meant "What was the droid that became the replacement for Luke's hand."

Comment: lol. No, but that would be awesome. Have a droid for a hand? Hells yeah.

Comment: The kind that gives you a brand new hand, and doesn't even get a "thank you" for his efforts.

Comment: @WadCheber - How about a big hand for that guy!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was a [Medical Droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Medical_droid). In particular, a 2-1B (Too-onebee; I believe that's the one that actually did the work) and an FX-7.

> Luke Skywalker was treated in a Bacta tank operated by two medical droids, a 2-1B and an FX-7, in the Echo Base medical lab shortly before the Battle of Hoth in 3 ABY. The same droids would replace Skywalker's hand with a cyborg replacement after losing it to Darth Vader on Bespin.

Answer (score 34):

The droid in question is 2-1B, a medical droid.

[image: Picture of 2-1B from the "waist" up. The droid is mostly humanoid in structure, but with far thinner arms than C-3PO. The head and chest are finished with a speckled bluish-grey metal, it has squared-off yellow eyes and a grill-like speaker where its mouth and nose would be. A thin hose is attached to its chin and others connect to its abdomen. A large bacta tank is visible in the background.]

From the [Star Wars Wiki](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/2-1B_surgical_droid):

> The droid model was highly advanced and intelligent with its programming being further advanced by some of the top physicians in the galaxy at the State Medical Academy of Rhinnal, which also integrated heuristic processors. The most useful characteristic of the 2-1B droids was the ease with which owners could update their programming and appendages. A 2-1B droid could easily become specialist in neurosurgery, podiatry, pediatrics, cybernetic limb replacement, and alien biology with a trip to a certified service center. While advanced, 2-1B droids were generally paired with an FX-series medical assistant droid for medical assistance and detailed patient analysis.

Comment: wish i could accept both answers. thanks.